# Conditional Formatting rows with shared Merged Cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I've got a little helper spreadsheet that I use, and there are some Merged Cells.

Rather than get rid of these, which I know can cause headaches, I was looking for an idea on fixing an issue.

I have a few rows that share a merged cell.  When this merged cell is not empty, I want the rows to highlight.  Currently, the formula (applied over `A1:B4`) is `=$B1<>""` and then a fill.  Works okay for the first row, but not the other three:
[image]

I was thinking I could add some more logic, but there's nothing really there for me.  It's a pretty simple table.  Unfortunately, there's not really a way to say (for rows 2:4), `if row 1 is colored, then color this row`...(Although I *think* I've seen clever uses of Named Ranges to do something like that, but I could be mistaken).

So, in A2, what's the conditional format formula "thinking"?  Is it going to `=$B2<>""`, in which case ...what's it looking for as `B2`? If I select `A2`, and look at the conditional format rule applied to the current selection, it still shows `=$B1<>""`.

Thanks for any ideas/tips.  It's not a huge deal, so I don't need a VBA solution - just maybe an idea or trick for using CF with merged cells.

Edit: For a more full explanation - the idea is that col. B will have an invoice number and if it's there, make the row a color.  I will be repeating this "chart" a bunch, and have some non-grouped companies, who have their own lines.  I just don't like the gap of color there in my group and was trying to get it to have a color when the first of the group does.

[image]

Comment: @BrakNicku - I'll update my post with a bigger shot of the table.  That might work, but I wanted to be able to use this on over 50 rows...

Comment: @BrakNicku - done!  If I use the anchored `$B$1`, then it doesn't work properly for the individual rows. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's perfectly clear now and obviously my first comment doesn't solve it, so I'll remove it. I'm also afraid it won't be possible without VBA.

Comment: @BrakNicku - Drats, I was afraid of that.  It's not important enough (again it's just a helper sheet) to warrant going down that path.  Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to base my CFR's on formulas.

[image: cfr_match]

After selecting all of column A and B I created a CF rule with the following.

```
=AND(LEN($A1), ISNUMBER(MATCH(1E+99, $B$1:$B1)))
```

The approximate [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) simply looks for the last number in the B column. I can see a missing invoice number in a cell like B7 would generate confusion but perhaps you can expand on this for conditions not demonstrated by your examples.

Comment: Oooh this looks promising!  Yeah, the only thing is there will be a time (before invoicing) where `B7` would be blank.  But would just putting even a space in there prevent the formatting from getting funky? I could leave some placeholder in there instead.

Comment: Could you leave a zero as a placeholder? A zero-length string won't get 'caught' when looking for 'last number' and with any modification to accommodate text you might as well just go on the length of column A.

Comment: Yeah, I could leave a 0.  What's the `1E+99`? If I do just `=1E+99`, there is not a number result.

Comment: `1E+99` is an impossibly large number; one that will never be reached. Literally a **1** followed by 99 zeroes. Through the use of an approximate match and $B$1:$B1 you are asking for the last number up to that row. The merged cells really only consider the cell in the top-left corner to be the cell referenced which is why you cannot look directly across; there is nothing there. But if say 'give me the last number you find in column B up to B5 the formula will find 123 in B2.

Comment: Ah, I know the convention `1E+99`, I didn't know you could enter it like that in Excel though.  Thanks for the explanation!  Even with the formula though, it's only highlighting `A1` and the merged cell.  It's not getting the A2:A5

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "placeholder" instead of blank cells (when there is no invoice), you could try the following formula:

```
=(LOOKUP(2,1/($B$1:$B1<>""),$B$1:$B1)<>"x")*LEN(A1)
```

With sample data it looks like this:

[image]

When the cell is left blank (no placeholder), column `A` is highlighted, column `B` is not.